# Validación de campo Angular con mínimo 2 palabras?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html5, required

¿Cómo hacer la validación de un campo Angular con mínimo 2 palabras?

Nombre y Apellidos (Nombre Completo): Este campo es obligatorio. Es un campo abierto en el que se debe permitir escribir caracteres alfabéticos. No se permiten caracteres o números especiales. Debe haber al menos dos nombres.

Comment: Kay, podrías usar una expresión regular como se muestra en esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25132036/4092887).

Comment: Hola Kay, deberias mostrar lo que has intentado para que sobre ello podamos ayudarte. Puedes probar mirando la respuesta que propone Mauricio o cualquier otra de [tag:regex] de este sitio. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Para esas validaciones se usa una directiva que de AngularJs que evalué expresiones regulares.

Esta se llama ngPattern

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern

Echale un vistazo a la documentacion donde te dan un ejemplo bastante claro y te dicen explican donde colocar la expresión regular.

Saludos.